# MongoDB and APIs: How to prevent posting incorrect data

Tags: mongodb, api

I am making an API in MongoDB. Suppose I want to make a leaderboard and the such, where after a game is over, the person & score is added to the database. Let's say someone gets a score of 100 on the game, my my code posts that information to the API. What's to stop someone from copy-pasting the same 'post' code into the console of the webpage, and sending that they got a score of 2000 instead. Any passwords I set will be visible in the code. Note that this is frontend code.

Comment: What you can do, is use some type of encryption and decryption while sending the score to leader-board, As it would not be able to modify the score.

Comment: My only problem is, anything I can do, someone can just copy-paste using something like the Chrome Dev Tools. What is to stop someone from copy-pasting any encryption code that I write? How can I tell the API what is my code, vs what is not?

Comment: There is nothing, as such that can be done. What one can do with the encryption key or string you have,

Comment: You can just authorise the request coming to your server i.e the client which is sending you the request by using http headers and enabling cors for verified domains

Comment: Ok, I guess that works. Thanks